# Why is there extra whitespace to the left of this standalone document when using siunitx?

Tags: margins, siunitx, standalone

I'm using the `standalone` document class. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    Hello world
\end{document}
```

The problem lies with `siunitx`. Using any of the following preamble lines do not result in the extra whitespace:

```
\usepackage{tikz}        % or
\usepackage{circuitikz}
```

But the following preamble lines result in the extra whitespace:

```
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}  %or
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

The problem also appears when I draw figures in a `circuitikz` environment. Why is there extra whitespace to the left of the compiled PDF? How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `preview` as the option (I don't know why it comes though):

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

As an alternative to using preview, the classical solution to all known spurious white space questions is to put a `%` at the end of a line somewhere. In this case, putting it here works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}



\begin{document}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

  Hello world


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

The problem here is that `siunitx` needs to execute some code right at the end of the `\document` macro. Currently, this is done by adding a couple of items to the 'right' of the macro, but this messes up the `\ignorespaces` at the end of it. I will address this with an updated `siunitx` later today.

---

Fixed in v2.5k, sent to CTAN 2012-11-13.